# I have a C# Windows Forms Application and I want the user to be able to schedule a recurring task

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, timer, .net-3.5

My application sends out an email based on data from the entered form on the UI.  The UI also allows them to "schedule" this as a job.  I don't really want to use outside classes, e.g. Quartz.  I also don't want to use the task scheduler as this would require completely rewriting my app... I understand that this can be done with timers, and I have attempted to use the Windows.Forms.Timer, however, I am not getting the desired results.  I want it to run at the user specified interval and time, until the set end date.

```
private void Submit_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool run = false;
        Location_Alert_Timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Location_Alert_Timer_Tick);

        if (Schedule_Chk.Checked == true)
        {
            run = true;

            if (Recur_Txt.Text != "" || Recur_Txt.Text != "0")
            {
                while (run == true)
                {

                    if ((Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")) <= Convert.ToDateTime(End_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text)))
                    {
                        //Execute_Command();
                        DateTime dt1;
                        DateTime dt2;
                        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(Recur_Txt.Text),0,0,0);
                        //TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,30);
                        dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
                        dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text);
                        if  (dt1 >= dt2)
                        {
                            Execute_Command();
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Interval = (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text + ":00.000").Add(ts) - DateTime.Now).Milliseconds;
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Start();
                            while (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")) <= Convert.ToDateTime(End_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text))
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Interval = (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text + ":00.000") - DateTime.Now).Milliseconds;
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Start();
                            while (exitFlag == false)
                            {
                                Application.DoEvents();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Location_Alert_Timer.Stop();
                        run = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Execute_Command();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Execute_Command();
        }
    }

    void Location_Alert_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")) <= Convert.ToDateTime(End_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text))
        {
            Execute_Command();
        }
        else
        {
            exitFlag = true;
        }
    }
```

My timer events do not seem to be firing right and I know it is because I have set them up incorrectly...

Here is the form UI:
[image: Form UI]

If anyone has a similar implementation in the future,  @itsmatt's explanation led me to rewrite my whole event, from the ground up...below is the final implementation, and it works fantastically:

```
        private void Submit_Btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool run = false;


        if (Schedule_Chk.Checked == true)
        {
            run = true;

            if (Recur_Txt.Text != "" || Recur_Txt.Text != "0")
            {
                while (run == true)
                {
                    if ((Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")) <= Convert.ToDateTime(End_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text)))
                    {
                        DateTime dt1;
                        DateTime dt2;
                        TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(Recur_Txt.Text),0,0,0);
                        dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"));
                        dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text);
                        if (dt1 >= dt2)
                        {
                            Execute_Command();
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text + ":00.000").Add(ts) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Start();
                            timerActive = true;
                            TimerHold();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text + ":00.000") - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
                            singleuse = true;
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Start();
                            timerActive = true;
                            TimerHold();
                            MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                            MessageBox.Show(DateTime.Now.Add(ts).ToString());
                            MessageBox.Show((Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Add(ts).ToString()) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Interval = Convert.ToInt32((Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Add(ts).ToString()) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds);
                            Location_Alert_Timer.Start();
                            timerActive = true;
                            TimerHold();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Location_Alert_Timer.Stop();
                        run = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void TimerHold()
    {
        while (timerActive)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }

    void Location_Alert_Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (singleuse)
        {
            if (uses < 1)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")) <= Convert.ToDateTime(End_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text))
                {
                    uses++;
                    //DoItOnce();
                    Execute_Command();
                }
                else
                {
                    timerActive = false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                singleuse = false;
                timerActive = false;
                Location_Alert_Timer.Stop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")) <= Convert.ToDateTime(End_Date.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + Recur_Time_Txt.Text))
            {
                //DoIt();
                Execute_Command();
            }
            else
            {
                timerActive = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you pretend to have you app running forever? from msdn "This timer is optimized for use in Windows Forms applications and must be used in a window."

Comment: use http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ for these kind of works

Comment: Why are you registering the tick event in the button callback?  Register it elsewhere.  And this runs on the UI thread.  Is that what you want?  Maybe not, right?  There are other timers available that aren't on the UI thread.

Comment: Howz the application behaving right now..? Is it responding at least..?

Comment: @Disposer As I stated in my original post:

I don't really want to use outside classes, e.g. Quartz

Comment: The reason I am shying away from using external classes is that I am fairly new to C# and you learn little by using pre-made implementations.  I wish to make myself more robust as a programmer, and I will need some programming basics under my belt.  Think of a construction worker, if he does not learn how to properly use a hand saw, one of the basic implements, then when there is some issue with the circular saw or he cannot use it for some reason, he will have nothing to fall back on.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper The app will be running on a server environment for extended periods of time.  This application sends out a pre-defined email template to a number of email addresses at a time and does so daily until the user defined alert period is over.

Comment: @itsmatt I am not sure about the implications of running it on the UI thread, and barring HUGE implications, I am fine with this, as the application is very lightweight. Can you provide any direction on proper registration?  I have been very unsuccessful so far in finding documentation on this and feel it is tied to my not knowing much about C# yet.  I was trained in console applications and have only been using Windows Forms Applications for about a month.

Comment: @kclewis Registering the tick event handler in the submit button click handler like you have will result in Location_Alert_Timer_Tick() being called once the first time the button is clicked, twice the next time, etc.  It is registering the same callback function over and over, which results in multiple calls to that when the tick event is raised.  Instead, += that event handler at init time (could be in the constructor or some other setup() function).  That way you get one and only one function call to Location_Alert_Timer_Tick() when the timer tick event is raised.

Comment: Ok, update:
Thanks to @itsmatt pointing out my ill-conceived tick event handler call placement, and rewriting my logic for the button click, I am slowly rebuilding the logic.  I believe I coded too much at once for my amateur coding skills.  I am building small steps upon a simple call.  Thank you all for your assistance.

Comment: @itsmatt If you propose the above registration comment as an answer, I will mark it as the answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kclewis Registering the tick event handler in the submit button click handler like you have will result in Location_Alert_Timer_Tick() being called once the first time the button is clicked, twice the next time, etc. It is registering the same callback function over and over, which results in multiple calls to that when the tick event is raised. Instead, += that event handler at init time (could be in the constructor or some other setup() function). That way you get one and only one function call to Location_Alert_Timer_Tick() when the timer tick event is raised.  Posted via community wiki for @itsmatt

Answer (score 2):

what about using something like this example?

[A-Simple-Scheduler-in-Csharp](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/591271/A-Simple-Scheduler-in-Csharp)

Comment: This example I think would work, but I was hoping to get this done with as little redefinition as possible.  Your aswer is a great one, and I may use it for a future implementation, but it may be a little complex for me right now... I'm new to this, and am looking for simple solutions, yet that allow me to do the work.

Comment: Well, I don't think there is a really simple reliable solution I'm afraid... You might be able to use some of the code from the example Project. I always feel I have no control what so ever when scheduling tasks inside a forms Application.